# What incentives do banks have to gather up loans into pools (backed by Ginnie Mae)and selling them?

Tags: mortgage, mortgage-rate

This is a two part question:

1) I understand that there are certain mortgage loans that when originated by banks can be gathered up into pools and then "sold" to investors, and that these pools are backed by Ginnie Mae, in the sense that, if the borrowers are unable to make payments, and the banks that originated them are also unable to make payments, then Ginnie Mae would step in and make the payments.

My first question is about the banks. What incentive do they have to gather up the loans in pools and sell them to investors? Because the payments made are not ending up in their pockets, but that of the investors instead.

2) Secondly, I've read that, in this process, Ginnie Mae collects a fee (of a max of six basis points). Who is this "fee" levied upon?

I hope my questions aren't too naive and simple to understand. Thanks!

Comment: Recommend reading The Big Short. Fun to read, interesting people in it, also details the CDO debacle, which is related to your question.

Comment: Didn't know The Big Short was a book. It's also a very entertaining and enlightening movie.

Comment: The answer to "What incentive do banks have to... ?" is either "MOAR PROFITZ!!1!" or "Damn, the law says we gotta do this."

Comment: @JoL The book is very good (among the best ones Micheal Lewis has written, in my opinion).

Comment: Ginnie Mae or not: Pooling averages the risk across many individual loans which makes the investment more predictable without the need to go into the dirty details of a loan. It's like buying an index fund as opposed to specific stock. But then (as The Big Short pointed out so brilliantly) *nobody at all **in the whole world*** looked at the details of the individual loans any longer, except for a single-digit number of guys, among them Michael Burry who actually enjoyed tables of numbers because it catered to his Asperger spectrum condition. Nobody else could be bothered.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Say I can lend money at a 10% rate. I lend you $10,000 and the note is for $11,000 due in one year. But, the next day, I can sell the note for $10,100, the buyer willing to get a return of 8.9%. ($11K/$10.1K). Why would I lend that $10K for a year, when I can turn over the loan and make 1% in a day?

The mortgage is more complex, of course. But the concept is similar. Underwriting the loan and selling it into a package (CMOs or Collateralized Mortgage Obligations) lets a small bank help their customer get the mortgage, but not have their funds tied up for decades. At the other end, are investors who can get a return on their money closer to the rate on long term loans.

The concept itself is sound so long at ethical underwriting is maintained, i.e. 20% down, 28/36 debt to income limits, etc. The market blew up when this was ignored, not because the premise was faulty.

The 6 basis points are skimmed from the payments homeowners make for the money then paid to the CMO holders.

Comment: Yes, this works great for the banks if they can more than double the amount of loans they sell by making risky loans.

Comment: @AbraCadaver And they can pass the risk off to others.

Comment: I can see this for Fannie Mae and Freddie Mac type loans, but doesn't the extremely low risk associated with Ginnie Mae loans change something?

Comment: In theory, the lower risk of GNMA means an investor will bid the price of the debt up, i.e. pushing the yield (investment return) lower.

Answer (score 0):

Legal scamming, basically. That is speaking about the pooling part, not the "selling a debt" part. There are good reasons for doing that.

When you pool up mortgages, you also hide the details of individual ones. That way you can begin to play statistics games and present averages of the size, risks and other factors. Just picking your average (mean, medium, mode? and there are more...) carefully can make the bundle look better than it is. And once the pool has been repackaged a few times, risky loans that nobody would want on their portfolio can become entirely invisible. Now find someone stupid enough to buy into an opaque financial construction and ... profit.

That is not exaggeration, that is exactly how the financial crisis happened. Not much has changed since then.

Comment: It's easier to sell a bad apple if you package it into a fruit basket and put it in the bottom of it.

Comment: @ViktorMellgren that's actually a great metaphor. I'd even expand it: You **can** sell an (unsellable) bad apple if you mix it with good apples, even without hiding. Buyers will value-judge the whole and consider it buyable. (there's a lot of psychology around this and how it affects the perceived value and all that).

Comment: Mixing apples with apples is maybe a better metaphor :)

Comment: @Tom - yep, 2008 financial rigging was more a big bushel of worm infested apples with bombs intentionally planted, and a coating of perfectly hand picked apples on top.

Comment: @Tom That was really only one part of the problem, though definitely one of the biggest. Another part of the problem was that the risk models that were used to evaluate the pools didn't take into account the possibility of a significant drop in the price of residential real estate over the entire country.

Comment: "When you pool up mortgages, you also hide the details of individual ones". No you don't. Maybe the buyer can't be bothered to look, but you have the name and address, and all the details from the application. And you can drive over to the house and talk to the guy if you want to.

Comment: @Ben I see you haven't followed the financial crisis well. The trick was to pool the pools again, then pool *those* pools again, and so on, until neither side the the trade quite understood what was inside anymore. Of course with a simple pool this doesn't happen.

Comment: @tom You are just plain wrong. The pools of pools of pools are all traceable back to the individual mortgages. One simply needed to decide to look.

Comment: If they are all Ginnie Mae backed mortgages do the details matter? Isn't the point of Ginnie Mae backing that the government steps in if there is a default?

Comment: The basic idea of pooling is sound, it's similar to diversifying a portfolio -- a few bad mortgages would be offset by all the good mortgages. But this assumes that there's no correlation between the holdings, and that's where the error was in the mortgage crisis. It's more like diversifying your portfolio among mutual funds that all own the same underlying stocks.

Comment: The correlation was that when mortgages defaulted, the property values around those homes dropped, causing a feedback effect on the entire real estate market.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz "a significant drop in the price of residential real estate over the entire country" That wasn't even the problem. If the real estate market merely _stopped growing as fast as it was_ the whole thing was going to come tumbling down. Which is what happened.